# how to return inner join from a view model web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a problem with returning inner join. I return the inner join in the repository and I database relations in the view model.

I have tried change the variable and replacing the result variable to another variable but the return is still null.

```
//Repository
public BarangViewModel GetBarang()
{
    var barang = new Barang();
    var detailbarang = new DetailBarang();
    var joinbarang =  _context.Barang.Join(_context.DetailBarang, p => p.IdBarang,
        m => m.IdBarang, (p,m) => new { barang = p, detailbarang = m });
    var result = new BarangViewModel();
    result.BarangV = barang;
    result.DetailBarangV = detailbarang;
    return result;
}

//View Model
 public class BarangViewModel
{
    public Barang BarangV { get; set; }
    public DetailBarang DetailBarangV { get; set; }
}

//Model Barang
public class Barang
{
    [Key]
    public int IdBarang { get; set; }
    public string Nama { get; set; }
    public int Jumlah { get; set; }
}

//model Detail
public class DetailBarang
{
    [Key]
    public int IdDetail { get; set; }
    public string Jenis { get; set; }
    public int Berat { get; set; }
    public DateTime TanggalDibuat { get; set; }
    public DateTime TanggalKirim { get; set; }
    public int IdBarang { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdBarang")]
    public Barang Barang { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: set result.DetailBarangV to joinbarang.detailbarang?

Comment: can you tell me more specifics ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to return all your data? or single data? You can set your join linq result with ToList() if you want to return all of your data or SingleOrDefault() if you want to return single data. The result of your join linq is the anonymous object. Let's do some dirty trick

Here if you want to return all of your data,
BarangViewModel

```
public class BarangViewModel
{
    public List<Barang> BarangV { get; set; }
    public List<DetailBarang> DetailBarangV { get; set; }
}
```

Repository

```
public BarangViewModel GetBarang()
{
     var barang = new List<Barang>();
     var detailbarang = new List<DetailBarang>();
     var joinbarang =  _context.Barang.Join(_context.DetailBarang, p => p.IdBarang,
     m => m.IdBarang, (p,m) => new { barang = p, detailbarang = m }).ToList();
     foreach (var item in joinbarang)
     {
     barang.Add(item.barang);
     detailbarang.Add(item.detailbarang);
     }
     var result = new BarangViewModel();
     result.BarangV = barang;
     result.DetailBarangV = detailbarang;

     return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you call

```
var joinbarang =  _context.Barang.Join(_context.DetailBarang, p => p.IdBarang,
    m => m.IdBarang, (p,m) => new { barang = p, detailbarang = m });
```

`joinbarang` becomes an anonymous object with properties `barang` and `detailbarang` that contains the data that you are querying for. You are not actually setting the variables you declared earlier

```
var barang = new Barang();
var detailbarang = new DetailBarang();
```

So when you are returning the viewmodel you should set the properties

```
result.BarangV = joinbarang.barang;
result.DetailBarangV = joinbarang.detailbarang;
```